# Data received is undefined for observable in Angular

Tags: angular

I have created an API using node that verifies if the user is valid or not and then creates a valid token for the verified user and passes it on otherwise returns 401, but on the angular part I always get undefined.

```
// used to authenticate the user and create the token
app.post("/auth", (req, res) => {
    
    if(req.body.email==="swarup@gmail.com" && req.body.pwd==="123456"){
        var token = jwt.sign({email: "user.email"}, 'hubDemo', {expiresIn: '1h'});
        res.send({token})
    }else{
        res.send(401)
    }
```

I have a service that calls this API in Angular:

```
 return this.http.post<{token: string}>("/api/auth",{email:email,pwd:pwd})
```

and I subscribe to it in a component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {GetvalidationService} from '../_services/getvalidation.service'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Appstate } from '../app.state';
import { loginEmail } from './../model/models.tut'
import * as LoginActions from '../action/action.tut';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    
      email: string; 
      password: string;
      data;
      public error: string;
    
      constructor(private validationService: GetvalidationService, private router: Router, private store: Store<Appstate>) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      onSubmit(){ 
    
        var a = this.validationService.authenticateLogin(this.email,this.password).subscribe((data)=>this.data=data);
        var b =this.error;
        var c= this.data;
        //store the email of logged in user in store
        this.store.dispatch(new LoginActions.AddLogin({name: this.email}) )
        this.router.navigate(['content'])
      }
    }
```

Comment: hey @Swarup Chavan I guess you have to send token like that  `res.send(token)`

Comment: can you write console log in subsribe for data  can tell us what does it say?